# Breusch Pagan and White test always 0

Tags: regression, machine-learning, p-value, breusch-pagan, white-test

I'm working on a machine learning algorithm and trying to evaluate the model based on a guide online. No matter how I change the features of the model, the results of both tests are always 0. Is there a problem with calculation or the model? I'm having a hard time understanding why this is happening from reading online, so anything helps! I'll place relevant code below

```
# Applying model to be used with the statsmodel package (needs a constant) 
X2 = sm.add_constant(X)

# create a OLS model
model = sm.OLS(Y, X2)

# fit the data
est = model.fit()

_, pval, __, f_pval = diag.het_white(est.resid, est.model.exog, retres = False)
print(pval, f_pval)

_, pval, __, f_pval = diag.het_breuschpagan(est.resid, est.model.exog)
print(pval, f_pval)
```

and the output

```
0.0 0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an extended comment because there isn't enough information.

It might be you running an old version, I am on 0.11.1 and according to the [the vignette](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_white.html#statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_white), there isn't an argument for `"retres="`:

```
statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_white(resid, exog)
```

And it returns:

```
lmfloat
The lagrange multiplier statistic.

lm_pvalue :float
The p-value of lagrange multiplier test.

fvaluefloat
The f-statistic of the hypothesis that the error variance does not depend on x. This is an alternative test variant not the original LM test.

f_pvaluefloat
The p-value for the f-statistic.
```

If I run it on an example dataset it works, so you need to show some examples of your dataset..

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats import diagnostic

np.random.seed(100)
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(50,5))
X2 = sm.add_constant(X)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,50)

model = sm.OLS(Y, X2)
est = model.fit()

_, pval, __, f_pval = diagnostic.het_white(est.resid, est.model.exog)
print(pval, f_pval)
#0.42367606624805376 0.47817512202760115

_, pval, __, f_pval = diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(est.resid, est.model.exog)
print(pval, f_pval)
#0.6693669871020579 0.6990024119539573
```